UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in /build/linux-1gzLWc/linux-6.8.0/drivers/gpu/drm/radeon/radeon_atombios.c:2718:34
This error occurred on my PC when booting Ubuntu from 22.04/24.04 in any flavor, in Zorin and also with Pop!_OS 22.04.
Looks like a new kernel issue. It seems to me that it has to do with Kernel 6.5, 6.8 +.
Should I be worried about this?
The problem does not occur in Fedora 39 or Debian 12.
May 15 18:36:36 pop-os kernel: ------------[ cut here ]------------
May 15 18:36:36 pop-os kernel: UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in /build/linux-1gzLWc/linux-6.8.0/drivers/gpu/drm/radeon/radeon_atombios.c:2718:34
May 15 18:36:36 pop-os kernel: index 48 is out of range for type 'UCHAR [1]'
May 15 18:36:36 pop-os kernel: CPU: 0 PID: 8 Comm: kworker/0:0 Not tainted 6.8.0-76060800daily20240311-generic #202403110203~1714077665~22.04~4c8e9a0
May 15 18:36:36 pop-os kernel: Hardware name: To Be Filled By O.E.M. To Be Filled By O.E.M./760GM-HD, BIOS P1.00 06/11/2019
May 15 18:36:36 pop-os kernel: Workqueue: events work_for_cpu_fn
May 15 18:36:36 pop-os kernel: Call Trace:
May 15 18:36:36 pop-os kernel:  <TASK>
May 15 18:36:36 pop-os kernel:  dump_stack_lvl+0x48/0x70
May 15 18:36:36 pop-os kernel:  dump_stack+0x10/0x20
May 15 18:36:36 pop-os kernel:  __ubsan_handle_out_of_bounds+0xc6/0x110
May 15 18:36:36 pop-os kernel:  radeon_atombios_parse_power_table_6+0x39c/0x3d0 [radeon]
May 15 18:36:36 pop-os kernel:  radeon_atombios_get_power_modes+0x247/0x270 [radeon]
May 15 18:36:36 pop-os kernel:  radeon_pm_init_dpm+0x8e/0x2f0 [radeon]
May 15 18:36:36 pop-os kernel:  radeon_pm_init+0xdf/0x120 [radeon]


Your question is not clear. You mention Ubuntu 20.04 any flavor. What does that mean? The mention of Pop OS is off topic on this site as well. Please clarify what is the exact version you are using. All the error messages are off topic as it is for Pop OS.

This is a message from the Linux Kernel's UNdefined Behavior SANititer (UBSAN), which tries to make hidden bugs obvious. It might be that some new checks were added, or newly enabled, and it is also likely the bug has been there all along. Atombios is AMD graphics generic interface to device specific code, so a warning about Atombios is likely a bug in a device specific data table for your GPU (distributed by AMD), not in the kernel specifically. I am seeing a similar warning, and if I figure out how to fix it I'll let you know here.
