Error during suspending my laptop
enter image description here
When I sleep my laptop and relaunch it it shows this error and it doesn’t respond to any button, I had to power it off!
Any solutions? (I have dual boot on that laptop)

Related but not identical: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1514186/ubsan-array-index-out-of-bounds-in-build-linux-1gzlwc-linux-6-8-0-drivers-gpu

Include details on your hardware - use "edit" to update your question. Unfortunately, the workaround may be not to use suspend.
